# C#: How to create a program that will only accept an integer value that's 0 or higher?

Tags: c#

For the program, if the user enters anything other than a number that's 0 or higher then the program would say "Invalid. Enter a number that's 0 or higher." The program would then continue to say "Invalid. Enter a number that's 0 or higher." again and again until a number of 0 or higher is entered.

The problem is that if I enter a letter the program does not respond with "Invalid. Enter a number that's 0 or higher."

This is all I can do so far:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string numberIn;
            int numberOut;

            numberIn = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(numberIn, out numberOut))
            {
                if (numberOut < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid. Enter a number that's 0 or higher.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your if's with:

```
while (!int.TryParse(numberIn, out numberOut) || numberOut < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid. Enter a number that's 0 or higher.");
    numberIn = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a loop of some sort. Perhaps a `while` loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string numberIn;
    int numberOut;

    while (true) 
    {
        numberIn = Console.ReadLine();

        if (int.TryParse(numberIn, out numberOut))
        {
            if (numberOut < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid. Enter a number that's 0 or higher.");
            }
            else
            {
                break; // if not less than 0.. break out of the loop.
            }
        }    
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Success! Press any key to exit");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple, neat approach, you can use this:

```
while (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry");
}

//Execute code if entry is correct here.
```

Every time the user enters a number, it checks to see if the number entered is less than 0. If the input is invalid, the `while` loop continues to loop. If the input is valid, the condition is false and the loop closes.